# sql datetime format

Tags: sql

I am trying to convert a date into this format YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss eg. 2007-01-05 23:00:00.  But my SQL leaves the string unchanged, can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
select convert(varchar,'23/02/2008 00:00:00',120)
```

Comment: Which database system?? What version / edition?? **SQL** is just the *Structered Query Language* - doesn't say which database you're really using, and these kinds of things are often vendor-specific....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '23/02/2008 00:00:00')`. All you're doing is converting a string into a string, which won't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

your data type needs to be DATETIME, eg:

`select convert(DATETIME, '23/02/2008 00:00:00', 120)`

Answer (score 0):

try this. Works for Transact-SQL.

```
select convert(datetime,'23/02/2008 00:00:00')
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

maybe you're looking to do this:

```
CONVERT(varchar,'23/02/2008 00:00:00',100) 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'
```

Answer (score 0):

select format(getdate(),'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm tt')

Answer (score -2):

Following is the syntax to achieve what you are looking for

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), GETDATE(), 120)

To know more about the date formats see the link 
http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Comment: That only gets you a string representation of the current date, not any date.